# How do specify folder location AND file type in Powershell

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, file, directory

I would like to use Powershell to look up folders containing a specific word, and then look inside those for a specific file type. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this with Powershell.

```
find . \
-type d -iname '*_OUTPUT' -maxdepth 2 \
-exec find {} -type f -iname '*.psd' -not -path "*.\_*" \; >> /Volumes/Path-to-output-folder/Output.csv
```

This is the Bash script I wrote that I run in Terminal. It works sometimes but it also crashes the SMB server connection regularly, because I'm running this on a Mac and it doesn't like the SMB server. So I want to try and do the same thing on a Windows machine because it has a reliable connection to the server.

What I'm doing here is going two folders deep of the starting directory `-maxdepth 2` and looking there for any folders that end with _OUTPUT `-type d -iname '*_OUTPUT'`. Then, looking inside those folders for any files with the extension .psd `-exec find {} -type f -iname '*.psd'`, ignoring hidden files which might get caught up in the search `-not -path "*.\_*"`. Any files found are output as the full path to a CSV sheet.

I can look up folders in Powershell using `-directory`, and look up file types using `Get-ChildItem`, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to combine them in the way I did above using Bash. Is there a Powershell master out there that could help?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by breaking it down:

```
# Finding folders with names ending in _OUPUT
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Depth 2 -Filter *_OUTPUT

# Finding files in a folder with the .psd extension
Get-ChildItem -Path .\folder\ -File -Filter *.psd
```

We can combine the two with the pipeline like so:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Depth 2 -Filter *_OUTPUT |Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.psd
```

Finally, use `Where-Object` to exclude files starting with `._`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Depth 2 -Filter *_OUTPUT |Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.psd |Where Name -notlike ._*
```

Comment: Ah I get it. Thanks. I didn't realize you could use Get-ChildItem twice like that. This looks like it should work but I'm getting the error message "a parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Directory'". I am on a work computer, I just found out we only have Powershell 2.0 installed! Which is kind of crazy.

Comment: @JamesTrory - you can filter the output in your `Where-Object` stage by testing for `$_.PsIsContainer`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks, that gets me a lot closer. PS 2.0 sucks. It doesn't accept `-File` or `-Depth` parameters. If I use `$_.PsIsContainer` in `Where-Object` that's helping to filter to only _OUTPUT folders, but it's not only giving me a list of the files it's also giving me a list of directories. I only want files. `Get-ChildItem -Recurse S:\Path -Filter *_OUTPUT | Get-ChildItem -Filter *.psd | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }`

Comment: @JamesTrory - you are welcome! [*grin*] ///// i would run G-CI & filter for the paths 1st, then run it for the files. that otta give you what you need.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey So would that look something like this? - `Get-ChildItem -Recurse S:\Path -Filter *_OUTPUT | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | Get-ChildItem -Filter *.psd | Export-Csv S:\whatever.csv`. This sort of works, but the CSV export contains not only the files inside _OUTPUT folders, but also the names of any sub-folders within them. I don't want the subfolders because it's cluttering up the list of files. Any idea how to stop that happening?

Comment: @JamesTrory - it looks like you will need to add a W-O filter stage after each G-CI call. they could _each_ filter on the `.PSIsContainer` ... the 1st testing _for dirs_ and the 2nd testing _for NOT dirs_.